# WebBrowser navigate via session cookie in window phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, browser

I am trying to login a website by **POST** method through `HttpWebRequest`. In the beginning, i create a portrait page to let user to enter username and password and access the web page. I successfully to Post the data and get the **HTML** content from the website. Finally I using the `Webrowser.NavigateTostring` method to display the website in the webBrowser I create.

**Problem 1**: Inside the webBrowser, I can not do any action in the website. In the *normal* webBrowser, after successfully login I can do any action such as go to event forum..but what i face is I can't navigate to event forum or any forum.

**Problem 2**: Inside the webBrowser, the image will not showing eg, user picture, product picture. I also trying to use `IsolatedStorage` method to show the **HTML** content but it also non work.

What I confusing is wheather the `Webrowser.NavigateTostring` method is a way to asynchronous operation to the website in internet? and what I doing wrong? or I looking for wrong direction?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way will suffer from these problems as if you load the HTML using `WebBrowser.NavigateToString` or from Isolated Storage none of the relative links to images, scripts or CSS will work. Also it is impossible to pass any Cookies from `HttpWebRequest` to the `WebBrowser`

The way to do this is to use the `WebBrowser` control itself to do the POST. There is a overload of the `WebBrowser.Navigate` method [as documented on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626636%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). That will allow you to POST data to your URL.

```
// generate your form data based on the data you got from your "portrait page" 
// and get the bytes from that.
// (e.g. write your post data to a MemoryStream as UTF8 and get its bytes)
byte[] formBytes = ...

// write HTTP headers here, including the type of data you're posting, e.g.:
string headers = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
   + Environment.NewLine;


Uri uri = ... // where you want the POST data to be sent

this.webBrowser.Navigate(uri, formBytes, headers);
```

That way your web browser will be properly initialized and your cookies, images, scripts and CSS should all work.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Annetts. Is header mean user-agent, content-type, Accept and other? This how to convert to a string? can give some explanation about it or edit you post? Appreciated.

Comment: Just content-type if I recall correctly. There are loads of other headers set by the browser control (including user-agent, accept...).

Comment: TankYou @Paul Annetts and great thanks. It work for me. ^^ Thank.

Comment: what about Set-Cookie:? is it possible to add Set-Cookie: header ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Set-Cookie is one of the HTTP headers that are not supported.