# How to add cookie in my web browser control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to add cookie in my web browser control.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(serverUrl));
```

Basically i need to put cookie value at the time of the navigation.How can i add cookie to this type request in windows phone 7

Let me explain my complete problem.

I have to send an Authentication key through cookies to the webrequest for the server to authenticate the client. In mobile devices like Android and iPhone, they have a Cookie container where the browser control takes the data from the cookie container. I expected WP7 to have similar facility, but I didnot find it. (Did I miss it ? if so please direct me.)

Please help me...Thanks

Comment: How about this? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/e43239f3-3914-43ec-ac50-223b022ec2ea

Comment: but i need the solution for windows phone

Comment: May i know the purpose of add cookie in webbrowser? is for authentication part?

Comment: yes,iam using cookie for authentication part

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100678/webbrowser-navigate-via-session-cookie-in-window-phone

Comment: this link will help u a lot...

Comment: webBrowser1.InvokeScript(“eval”, “document.cookie = \”Settings=foobar\””);  Itried this but iam getting An Error         "an unknown error has occurred. error: 80020006"

Comment: Maybe this will work for you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830586/setting-a-cookie-in-a-webbrowser-control

Comment: @ Potecaru Tudor I tried this but iam getting an error .i want the solution for Windows phone  Web Browser control not for .net

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work or not.
But you can call JavaScript functions inside a page from C# using Web Browser control
and in JavaScript you can set the cookie. To call JavaScript functions of Web Browser controls see the link below.

```
 webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript(jsfunctionname, parameters);
```

http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/

Comment: i think this is not applicable in Windows phone

Comment: This is possible in some cases. You can use [Browser.InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee652559(v=vs.95).aspx). You can see a working solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287409/windows-phone-webbrowser-set-cookies). Regards.